# Test Windows Forms for different app.config files

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, testing, configuration-files

Our Windows Forms Application is configured by the app.config file, there are 100+  machines running and there are multiple configurations.
I would like to test the application with different app.config files, I do this by calling the static main function of the Windows Forms Project, which then calls one form of many depending on the config file.

I would like to start a test with a given config.file:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ConfigEurope()
{
    string[] args = new string[1];
    args[0] =  "C:\app.Europe.config";
    Program.Main(args);
}

[TestMethod]
public void ConfigAsia()
{
    string[] args = new string[1];
    args[0] =  "C:\app.Asia.config";
    Program.Main(args);
}
```

How do I programmatically set the config file? How can I test whether the proper form runs? I cannot change the architecture of the application.

many thanks

Answer (score 1):

The right option would be to have the configuration files for different variation. Ex:

```
app.debug.config
app.europe.config
app.usa.config
app.china.config
```

etc. In this way we can have a base app.config file and then have separate config files for each of your distinguishing scenario.

As a next step, you have to create configurations in your projects for the following

```
debug
europe
usa
china
```

etc..

The final step would be to choose a configuration and then run your tests, or if you are running from the command line, you can use the `/p:Configuration=` parameter to pick the right configuration to run your test suite against.

For setting up the configurations for multiple cases, please refer the below blog post.

https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ManagingMultipleConfigurationFileEnvironmentsWithPreBuildEvents.aspx